# How to show details in separate line, rather than in same line

Tags: c#

Hope everyone is well,

I am a newb to C# and starting an online class soon however I have been doing my own thing and I am stuck with wanting to make a change to the below code

Console.Write("Input First Name: ");
string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

```
        Console.Write("Input Last Name: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Input your Email: ");
        string email = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Input your D.O.B: ");
        string dob = Console.ReadLine();

        string details = $"Full detail is: {firstName} {lastName} {email} {dob}";
        Console.WriteLine(details);
```

However, the result shows the details all in one line in command prompt, I would like to show the firstName, lastName, email and dob in seperate lines.

I would appriciate your advise/guide on this.

Thank you

Comment: use `{firstName}{Environment.NewLine}{lastName}{Environment.NewLine}{email}{Environment.NewLine}{dob}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\n` as a new line separator, however, it's recommended to use `Environment.NewLine` which would give `\r\n` in Windows, and `\n` in Unix based environments. This would ensure cross-platform compatibility.

example :

```
string details = $"Full detail is: {firstName}{Environment.NewLine}{lastName}{Environment.NewLine}{email}{Environment.NewLine}{dob}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \n in your output string `{firstName}\n{lastName}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "\n" in your String, like the following:

```
string details = $"Full detail is: {firstName}\n{lastName}\n{email}\n{dob}";
```

The "\n" indicates a line break. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions) about Character Escapes!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```csharp
        string details = $"Full detail is:\r\n{firstName}\r\n{lastName}\r\n{email}\r\n{dob}";
        Console.WriteLine(details);
        //You can also use Environment.NewLine as new line separator,
        // but in this case it makes the output not very readable



        //Or just:
        Console.WriteLine("Full detail is:");
        Console.WriteLine(firstName);
        Console.WriteLine(lastName);
        Console.WriteLine(email);
        Console.WriteLine(dob);
```

`Console.Write` won't add a new line at end of the output.

`Console.WriteLine` **does** add a new line at the end of the ouput

Answer (score 0):

Everybody has been suggesting the `\n` or `{Environment.NewLine}` which is a very much correct way to doing what you asked but for the sake of educating you use the special character `@` which serves as a verbatim identifier. E.g.

```
    string lastName = "Bob";
    string email = "test@test.com";
    string dob = "12-07-2022";

    string details = @$"Full detail is:
    {lastName}
    {email}
    {dob}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *joining* with `Environment.NewLine` delimiter:

```
Console.WriteLine(
  $"Full detail is: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, firstName, lastName, email, dob)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `console.write` instead of `writeline`? The difference between those two is basically to write the outputs in the same line or different lines:

```
Console.Write("Input Last Name: ");
string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Input your Email: ");
string email = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Input your D.O.B: ");
string dob = Console.ReadLine();

string details = $"Full detail is: {firstName} {lastName} {email} {dob}";
Console.Write(details);
```